# Jasminerice: spec failing because jQuery is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rubygems, coffeescript, jasmine

I just installed the gem Jasminerice in a Ruby-on-rails project. Following the instructions on [Jasminerice Github](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice) I created a spec, started the rails server, and navigated to the /jasmine route.

Although the spec was written to pass, it failed with ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `spec/javascripts/spec.js.coffee`

Simply add the line `#= require jquery`
before `#= require_tree ./`

Comment: I experienced this, too, but I assume most others haven't. Any idea why everyone hasn't run into this? I don't know if it's related, but the jasminerice gem installation didn't result in foo.js.coffee or bar.js.coffee getting installed to /app/assets/javascripts and I had to copy them there by hand from the gem source to even get to the failure described here. (Note: I haven't created any new specs - I was just trying to get the examples to run which themselves depend on jquery.)